# PHP: Get selected items from selection list

Tags: php, arrays, list, selection

I creating a  web based user order portal. I have a list with all user groups. You can select multiple groups and can add it to another list (selectedGroups). In the selectedGroups-list you can also remove items. That works pretty fine!

The lists construction is in my order.php. After you submitted the order you get a summary site (save.php). On this page, I need all items from the selectedGroups list. Unfournately `$__POST`, `$_GET` and many other ways did not work. I am getting other attributes from the order.php in save.php.

This is the list in my order.php:

```
<select id="SelectedGroups" name="SelectedGroups[]" size="5" multiple disabled="true"> 
</select>
```

(the selection list is just on initialization diabled)

This is my current code in save.php:

```
$Selection = $_POST['SelectedGroups'];

if(empty($Selection)) {
    echo 'Es wurde keine Gruppe ausgewählt!';
} else {
    foreach ($Selection as $selectedOption) {
        echo($selectedOption . "</br>");
    }
}
```

But I tried many different ways. Never time I get the SelectedGroups-Items.

Thanks in advance for any help!

--- Edit: 14.04., 13:55 ---

This code fill the "Groups"-List:

```
<?php

                                # Abfrage
                                $result = null;
                                $sql= 'SELECT * FROM dbo.Groups';
                                $query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

                                if (sqlsrv_has_rows($query)){
                                    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){
                                        $result[] = $row['Groupname'];
                                    }
                                }


                                echo "<select id='Groups' name='Groups' size='5' multiple disabled='true'>";
                                    for($i = 0; $i < count($result);$i++){
                                        echo "<option value=". $i .">" . $result[$i] . "</option>";
                                    }
                                echo "</select>";

                                    ?>
```

And with this I transfer the entry from "Groups" to "selectedGroups":

```
<label><input type="button" value="Hinzuf&uuml;gen" id="btn_add" name="add" disabled="false" onclick="move(this.form.Groups,this.form.SelectedGroups);"/></label>
```

--- Edit: 15.04., 11:45 --- 
the form line:

```
<form action="./index.php" method="get" novalidate autocomplete="off" class="idealforms">
```

Comment: There might be two reasons: Either your list do not have any options (runtime) or the form method is not post.

Comment: Show us your `<form action=` ect.. Are you posting it as a method and are you sending it to the correct file? also have your `<options>` got values?

Comment: I can't see any issue with the form/action because I get other data (for example the e-mail-adress) without problems.

Answer (score 1):

The drop down is disabled.

Disabled HTML form elements do not get posted.

Change

```
<select id="SelectedGroups" name="SelectedGroups[]" size="5" multiple disabled="true"> 
                    </select>
```

To

```
<select id="SelectedGroups" name="SelectedGroups[]" size="5" multiple> 
                    </select>
```

Comment: yes, it is disabled on start. You have to choose by radio buttons if you will select each group or just a department.

Comment: <label><Input type="radio" id="Gruppen" name="rdo_Grp" value="Gruppen" onclick="input=document.getElementById('Groups');
      if(document.getElementById('Gruppen').checked){
      input.disabled = false; 
      document.getElementById('SelectedGroups').disabled=false;}"

Comment: it seems that $_POST['SelectedGroups'] is empty